# How do I achieve a page-over-the-background effect with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design. I want to make my page look something like the one here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200501/turning_a_list_into_a_navigation_bar
where there's a rounded rectangle over the grey background that holds all the content. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic HTML and CSS style that page is currently using. So, they're wrapping all of their content in a `<div>` and applying that specific style class to the `div`.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    ...Content...
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    min-width: 0;
}
body {
    color: #333333;
    font: 100%/1.4 Georgia,serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 830px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 62em;
}
<!--wrap class css code-->
.wrap {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFF0;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Remember the border-radius and box-shadow with webkit prefixes (for older webkits) and with no prefix (for all modern browsers).

Comment: Added the additional style tags Rich is talking about.