# How to make a central background over the page in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to add the content of a page to a part of the background. That is, I want to keep 2 unutilized columns of area on both sides of the main content. 
Something like [this](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/#news),where you can see 2 unused bluish areas on either sides of the main content. There also is a shadow effect seen. So the main white background area where content is typed must be an image.

How do I achieve these things?

I need to know how I can actually put another sheet over the whole page seen in the screen.
(I'm referring to the 2 unused columns in the link ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There also is a shadow effect seen. So the main white background area
>   where content is typed must be an image.

Ummm... no. The shadow can be done using `box-shadow` on the main area. And you can center the main area using `margin: 25px auto;`

Example http://dabblet.com/gist/2793972

Comment: Grows vertically, yes. Horizontally, you could remove the fixed width and put a value in px or em or % for lateral margins.

Comment: I saw [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882560/how-do-i-achieve-a-page-over-the-background-effect-with-html-css/7882593#7882593), attributes like,-webkit-border-radius, -moz-border-radius,but could find no hits on google.
Are they needed?

Comment: Depends on what browsers you wish to support. IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5.1+, Opera 10.5+ support the unprefixed version. A detailed table for what `box-shadow` browser support here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow and for `border-radius` http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius // **EDIT** They are not attributes. They are just prefixed property names.

Comment: If you don't wish to bother with prefixes and you don't have a problem with relying on JavaScript to make the CSS eye candy work in all browsers, you could write only the unprefixed versions and use something like -prefix-free http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Tools (F12 in IE and Chrome) are an amazing thing.

For instance, if you tried using them you would see that the body has:

```
margin: 2em 3% 10em;
box-shadow: 0px 0.3em 1em #000;
```

And that the `html` element has:

```
background-color: rgb(220, 227, 230);
```

And, as if by magic, there is a "bluish" background and a shadow on the main content. Amazing.

Comment: Is there something similar in Mozilla Firefox?